# how to extract parts of file into separate files in linux using awk or grep or sed commands

Tags: awk, grep

I have text file as shown below:

Input file1.txt

```
.......................
cha21   1       3       5       nar
cha21   2       3       6       piy
cha23   2       3       5       ram
cha23   3       3       3       dam
cha27   5       3       7       pam
................................
```

And I would like to extract all the 5 columns corresponding to rows of "cha21", "cha23" and "cha27" into 3 different output files(for instance, cha21.txt, cha23.txt, cha27.txt).

output files

cha21.txt

```
..........
cha21   1       3       5       nar
cha21   2       3       6       piy
......................
```

cha23.txt

```
cha23   2       3       5       ram
cha23   3       3       3       dam
...................................
```

cha27.txt

```
cha27   5       3       7       pam
...........................
```

I can do this using grep command 3 times for 3 files...
Is there anyway I can do this all at once, i.e. one command because I need to extract 100 output files.

Comment: Are those dots present in the original file? Because the solutions below would have a subtle effect if run on a file like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try

```
awk '{print >> $1 ".txt" ;}'
```

where

- `print` print the whole line.
- `>> $1 ."txt"` write (append) this line to the file indicated by $1, with `.txt` added.

edit:

in case you have comment lines, lines with dots, etc

try

```
awk '$1 ~ /cha/ {print >> $1 ".txt" ;}'
```

which would only fill file begining with 'cha'.

Comment: This creates a file named `..................................txt` on my computer.

Answer (score 6):

It is easy with `awk`:

```
awk '{print $0 >> $1".txt"}' file1.txt
```

Comment: Why `print $0` and not just `print`? Are there versions of awk that need the explicit `$0` ?

Comment: This also creates a file named w/ a lot of dots on my machine. That can't be the expected behavior - what am I doing wrong?